# I need to append dates into one list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have strings looks like JSONs. if I print the type of them the output will be `str`.

```
{"date": "2022-09-14 15:22:53.084456"}
{"date": "2022-09-14 11:37:33.753514"}
```

I did convert them into real JSONs. Using this:
`i = json.loads(i)`

Now `print(i)` will output this:

```
{'date': '2022-09-14 11:37:33.753514'}
```

And `print(type(i))` will output this:

```
<class 'dict'>
```

And `print(type(i['date']))` will output this:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Now convert it to real date, and append the dates to a list `dates`:

```
date = datetime.strptime(i['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
if date > datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24):
    dates = []
    dates.append(date)
    if len(dates) > 0:
        print(len(dates))
```

Output:

```
1
[datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 10, 56, 36, 284933)]
1
[datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 11, 37, 33, 753514)]
```

The problem here I'm appending them to a list! But instead of adding all the dates into one list, it's creating a list for each date.

Wanted result:

```
print(len(dates))
2
```

Comment: Is this embedded in a loop? Or where do you execute this code?

Comment: You assign a list containing one element to date_count. Therefore its length will be 1. What were you expecting?

Comment: @jarmod *dates.push(date)* ?

Comment: @Vlad No Sir, the dates are 2. So I wanna add them to a list so its length will be 2. But instead, it's creating a list for every date...

Comment: @Samarakayed Please show how you're getting *date* from your JSON. Also, are you familiar with the built-in *append()* method for lists?

Comment: you are just printing. You are not adding anything to the list

Comment: How about calling the list `dates` instead of `date_count`. Initialize it using `dates = []` and then add to it using `dates.append(date)`.

Comment: @Vlad oops, too much jumping between JS and Python. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @Samarakayed You are initialising the *dates* list for every value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's invent some code that will (hopefully) enlighten you:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# a dictionary containing some date/time values as strings
JSON = {"dates": ["2022-09-14 10:56:36.284933", "2022-09-13 10:56:36.200000"]}
# a list of dates
dates = []
# iterate over the dates in the dictionary
for ds in JSON["dates"]:
    # convert to a datetime object
    date = datetime.strptime(ds, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    # check range
    if date > datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=24):
        # append to the list
        dates.append(date)
# print the list
print(dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you obtain the `date` variable, but every time it has a new value, you need to append it to the list:

```
dates = []
dates.append(date)
```

**Update:**

Move `dates` declaration outside of the `if` statement:

```
date = datetime.strptime(i['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

dates = []
if date > datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24):
    dates.append(date)
    if len(dates) > 0:
        print(len(dates))
```